# User-friendly Windows Mobile installer

Tags: deployment, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I'm looking for a way to create a small installer for Windows Mobile 5.0 and higher applications that contains my software and loads appropriate .NET CF 3.5 CABs. At the same time I also do not want to bloat my installer unnecessarily.

The [.NET Compact Framework 3.5 redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=E3821449-3C6B-42F1-9FD9-0041345B3385&displaylang=en#AffinityDownloads) is over 33 MB large. Is all of this really required? If not, where can I get the .NET CF 3.5 CABs for windows Mobile 5.0 and higher.?

Thanks,

Adrian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Compact Framework is more like 9 MB (well it's can be up to 12MB for MIPS processors I think).  The 33MB "redistributable" is the desktop installer that installs the CABs for all processors on a development PC.  That's *not* what you push to a device.

Comment: I understand that, but where do I get the CF Cabs from then? Or are there so many different processors for Windows Mobile devices that I still have to tell my users to download the entire 35 MB redist package?

Comment: Download the redistributable and install it on your PC.  You then have all of them, and you can "redistribute" whichever one you want.  WinMo only has one processor (ARM), so that CAB (NETCFv35.wm.armv4i.cab, 2644kB) is all you're going to need.